# How to change animation of material "mat-progress-bar " to start from 0 instead of 100?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, progress-bar

I am using progress bar from material on angular:

```
<mat-progress-bar  mode="determinate" value="40"></mat-progress-bar>
```

when I refresh the page, I notice the progress bar starts with 100 and then reduce the value to 40. Is there a way to change this behavior, so that progress bar starts with 0 and increase to 40?

Comment: not enough info  here to understand problem. this line doesn't give info to us.

Comment: if you put the line in the html of angular component, which will render the progress bar. Then, if you refresh the page, you will notice the progress bar starts at 100 and the animation of filling is reducing to 40.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is related to this [mat-progress-bar bug.](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20369)
Even tough one user mentioned he cannot reproduce it anymore in Angular 13, the issue still seems to be present.

One workaround is to disable the transitions:

```
.mat-progress-bar .mat-progress-bar-fill {
    transition: none !important;
}
```